# android html5 jquery code in assets not working correctly

Tags: android, jquery, html

On my code i get html from server and attach to it a jquery script
that replace some divs with a custom html5 canvas.

i wrote code in jquery and attach it to the assets folder of my project.
almost all code functionality working fine, i just get all the time this error:

```
10-18 09:44:04.890: E/Web Console(3595): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined at file:///android_asset/sketch.js:104
```

but when i running the same html with the same javascript code in the ripple plugin or just in a broswer all works just fine...

thanks in advance!

Comment: what android version did you use?

Comment: hi NAYOSO, im using version 2.2

Comment: Hmmm I think 2.2 not fully supported HTML5,maybe it's the problem,please see the answer for the reference

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because android 2.2 didn't fully support HTML5
you can see it in here -> http://mobilehtml5.org/
last month I'm also trying to develop an HTML5 application using google graph API 
it's work very well in samsung galaxy note (ICS) but didn't show anything in samsung galaxy S2 (gingerbread)

Comment: hi NAYOSO, thanks for your answer. in my code im working with a sketch canvas, i see that i can draw horizontal lines bot not vertical... i can see that this feature works fine... so how its possible?

Comment: and in your link i see that the touchevents and the canvas api is supported on android 2.2 and above. and thats what im using.

Comment: ah I see I see,so it's different,hmmm what is actually pageX?

Comment: e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX on touchmove and touchstart events.

Comment: Hmmm I'm still not sure but last week I encounter a problem with HTML and javascript in asset folder,I can't access the javascript and I must merge all my file (the HTML and javascript) into one HTML file,from what I read,it's actually a problem in android 3.0 to 4.03,but maybe you want to give it a try?

Comment: hi, i can access to the js files, and almost all features works fine. i have changed something and now i get this error:   10-18 10:43:52.930: W/webview(4790): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.

Comment: I'm sorry daniel but I have never meet that error,but maybe this one can help -> http://uihacker.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-bug-miss-drag-as-we-are-waiting.html